# How to extract number from string with dots and commas using regex

Tags: python-3.x

```
import re
b = "$2,01,468.75"
c = re.findall("\d+\.*\d+",b)
print(c)
```

Is there solution to get number which has multiple commas. Required solution: 2,01,468.75

Comment: `re.findall("[\d.,]+", b)`

Comment: `.*` matches any string, as much as possible, so your attempt would extract `1 and 2 and 3,` from `"all the stuff between 1 and 2 and 3, inclusive"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `([\d\,\.]*)`

```
import re
b = "$2,01,468.75"
c = re.findall("[\d\,\.]*",b)
print(c)
```

For working with regex I use this https://pythex.org/

Comment: Probably use `+` instead of `*`. The comma is not a regex metacharacter, so it should never require a backslash, and a dot inside a character class also does not need a backslash escape.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```py
import re
b = "$2,01,468.75"
c = re.findall("[\d\,\.]+",b)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
['2,01,468.75']
```

This regex ( `[\d\,\.]+` )finds one or more of a digit, comma or full stop.

Or if you want your output to be one string instead of a list of string(s), you could do:

```py
import re
b = "$2,01,468.75"
c = "".join(re.findall("[\d\,\.]+",b))
print(c)
```

Output:

```
2,01,468.75
```